# Outsource Stack and Filereader from Main Class

Tags: java, android, stack

Hello i'm a little bit lost and could use some help.
So basically i got a stack of Objects, in this case Strings.

```
public class Showall extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
        Stapel<String> s = new EVLStapel<String>();


        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            add();


            setContentView(R.layout.activity_showall);
         init();


        }
```

and i'm running the add() method, which is just reading a textfile and pushes an object with 3 values into my stack
& init() method, which is basically pulling them out of the stack again:

```
public void add(){
    AssetManager mngr;
    String line = null;


    try{
        mngr = getAssets();
        InputStream is = mngr.open("ausgabe.txt");
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] parts = line.split(",");
                s.push(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);





        }
        br.close();
    }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   


}
```

Here the important part of init():

```
 while(s.isEmpty() == false)
    {
    TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
    TextView p = new TextView(this);
     p.setText(s.peek());

       row.addView(p);

       TextView sp = new TextView(this);
       sp.setText(s.peek1());
       row.addView(sp);

       TextView pp = new TextView(this);
       pp.setText(s.peek2());
       row.addView(pp);
       table.addView(row);
       s.pop();
   }
```

So now my problem. I want to outsource my stack and the add method because, i will be using this method in many different classes and would be much less work if i could make a separated class for my stack and my filereader.
But i have no idea how.
I tried something like:

```
public class Reader extends ActionBarActivity {
 Stapel<String> s = new EVLStapel<String>();

     public void  add(){
            AssetManager mctr;
            String zeile = null;


            try{
                mctr = getAssets();
                InputStream is = mctr.open("ausgabe.txt");
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
                while((zeile = br.readLine()) != null)
                {

                    String[] parts = zeile.split(",");
                        s.push(parts[0], parts[1], parts[2]);


                        zeile = br.readLine();



                }
                br.close();
            }catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }   




     }      
}
```

and change this in my main class

```
public class Showall extends ActionBarActivity implements OnClickListener {
    Reader r = new Reader();
...
while(s.isEmpty() == false)
        {
        TableRow row = new TableRow(this);
        TextView p = new TextView(this);
         p.setText(r.s.peek());

           row.addView(p);

           TextView sp = new TextView(this);
           sp.setText(r.s.peek1());
           row.addView(sp);

           TextView pp = new TextView(this);
           pp.setText(r.s.peek2());
           row.addView(pp);
           table.addView(row);
           r.s.pop();
       }
```

Edit:
EVLStapel code:

```
public class EVLStapel<T> implements Stapel<T>{
    private class Item {
        public Item next;
        public T value;
        public T value1;
        public T value2;
      }
      private Item first;
      private Item last;
      private Item pre;

      public boolean isEmpty() {
            return first == null;
                }

public void push(T e, T e1, T e2)
{
        Item item = new Item () ;
        item.next = null;
        item.value = e ;
        item.value1 = e1;
        item.value2 = e2;
        if (isEmpty()) {
              first = item;
              first.next = null;
            }
            else {
                pre = first; 
                 first = item;
              first.next = pre;

            }

          }

public T peek() {

    if (isEmpty()) {
          throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException();
        }


        return first.value;
}
        public T peek1() {

            if (isEmpty()) {
                  throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException();
                }


                return first.value1;
        }
public T peek2() {

    if (isEmpty()) {
          throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException();
        }


        return first.value2;
}
public void pop() {
    if (isEmpty()) {
          throw new java.util.NoSuchElementException();
          }

         first = first.next;



      }

    }
```

Comment: So what part of that isn't working, and in what way?

Comment: using the stack from my Reader class in my Showall class. I'm getting a Nullpointer Exception. What i would like to do is, create a Stack of objects in my case Strings in the Reader class. And i would like to use this stack later in my init() method inside my showall class.

Comment: It usually doesn't work very well, if at all, to try to share objects between activities.  You're better off making it Parcelable or Serializable, and passing from one activity to the next via the Intent.  And is that your own stack class you've written or from a library?

Comment: it should be working f.e. this works perfectly fine:
public static void main(String args[])
{
 
 init();
}
public static void init()
{
 
 Reader r = new Reader();
 r.add();
 while(r.s.isEmpty()==false){
   System.out.println(r.s.peek());
   System.out.println(r.s.peek1());
   System.out.println(r.s.peek2());  
   r.s.pop();
 }
 }

Comment: Sure, if everything is static you're fine.  Will these be static methods?

Comment: that's not working with the bufferedreader

Comment: In what way is it not working?